# Need help in Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

I am rewriting a tool from old .net to .net 4.0 and am using Linq.  I am new to Linq and became stuck when solving the following problem:

I have a table called `UserInfo` with all the columns needed.  However, I need a specific data and need to do as follow but in Linq.  Can someone please help me with Linq query syntax?  Any help much be appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help with this matter.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.liProviderKey
FROM         UserInfo a INNER JOIN
            UserInfo b ON a.strBusinessType = b.strBusinessType AND
    (a.strCity = b.strCity AND a.strZip = b.strZip AND a.strState = b.strState AND 
            a.strCompanyName = b.strCompanyName AND (a.strDotNum = b.strDotNum OR
            a.strFedTaxNum = b.strFedTaxNum OR
            a.strPhone = b.strPhone)) OR
            (a.strSSN = b.strSSN AND a.strLastName = b.strLastName AND a.strbusinessType='Consumer')
WHERE     (b.liUserKey = @UserID AND a.fActive=1 AND a.fAuthenticated=1)
```

Comment: Paste entities definitions of those 2 tables, so it would be easier to help you. Also, some actual effort shown would be nice, because "stuck" suggest you were onto something.

Comment: Adding your attempted linq query in C# on a C# collection would let us answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Using method syntax:

```
DataContext dc = new DataContext(ConnectionString);
var result = dc.UserInfos.Join(dc.UserInfos, 
                               a => new { strBusinesssType == a.strBusinessType, ..., strSSN = a.strSSN }, 
                               b => new { strBusinesssType == b.strBusinessType, ..., strSSN = b.strSSN }, 
                               (a, b) => new { aTable = a, bTable = b })
                         .Where(o => o.bTable.liUserKey == @UserID && o.aTable.fActive == 1 && o.aTable.fAuthenticated == 1)
                         .Select(o => o.aTable.liProviderKey).Distinct();
```

Using query syntax:

```
var query = from a in UserInfos
               join b in UserInfos on new { a.strBusinessType, ..., a.strSSN } equals new { b.strBusinessType, ..., b.strSSN }
               where b.liUserKey == @UserID && a.fActive == 1 && a.fAuthenticated == 1
               select a.liProviderKey;
query = query.Distinct();
```

If you want a complex comparison, you'll have to do the join in the where clause.  Here you would remove the join and replace it with a second from (again, query syntax):

```
var query = from a in UserInfos
                   from b in UserInfos 
                   where b.liUserKey == @UserID && a.fActive == 1 && a.fAuthenticated == 1 &&
                         ((a.strBusinessType == b.strBusinessType) && ([rest of your conditions]))
                   select a.liProviderKey;
query = query.Distinct();
```

Comment: Both of the code samples you've provided use lambda expressions, and body of them are LINQ.  One uses query syntax to leverage both of those features, letting the compiler compile it into method syntax, and one is the direct creation of typical method syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this.  I still have questions;

Comment: how do I get systax to work when i want to separate (a.strCity = b.strCity AND a.strZip = b.strZip AND a.strState = b.strState AND 
                a.strCompanyName = b.strCompanyName AND (a.strDotNum = b.strDotNum OR
                a.strFedTaxNum = b.strFedTaxNum OR
                a.strPhone = b.strPhone)) OR a.strPhone = b.strPhone)) OR
                (a.strSSN = b.strSSN AND a.strLastName = b.strLastName AND a.strbusinessType='Consumer')